# How to properly store date from form datepicker into mongodb with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular-material-6

I'm using Angular Material 6's Datepicker and it displays the date using this format **06/20/1992** and in my browser console this is the output **Sat Jun 20 1992 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)**. Now when I console.log req.body in node, it outputs like this **1992-06-19T16:00:00.000Z'**. It is one day off.

Below is what I've done so far.

```
var thisDate = new Date(req.body.birthdate);
var currentMonth = thisDate.getMonth() + 1;
var currentDay = thisDate.getDate();
var currentYear = thisDate.getFullYear();

console.log(thisDate); // 1992-06-19T16:00:00.000Z
console.log(currentMonth + '/' + currentDay + '/' + currentYear); //6/20/1992
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? I'm going to save it to the database (mongodb)

Comment: The difference is UTC vs your local time zone - which one do you want?

Comment: I'm not sure right now but it would be better to see the side-to-side difference

Comment: JS doesn't have a lot of built-in date formatters - you can get the UTC version of the string you want with `getUTCMonth`, `getUTCDate` and `getUTCFullYear`. If you're doing a lot of date manipulation, consider using [Moment](http://momentjs.com) - for example, with Moment, the format you want is `moment().format('D/M/YYYY')`

Comment: @ic3b3rg thanks for that. definitely, moment is the solution I need. If you could post your comment as answer to mark it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS doesn't have a lot of built-in date formatters - you can get the UTC version of the string you want with `getUTCMonth`, `getUTCDate` and `getUTCFullYear`.

If you're doing a lot of date manipulation, consider using [Moment](http://momentjs.com) - for example, with Moment, the format you want is `moment().format('D/M/YYYY')`

Answer (score 0):

It is because your MongoDB saves the dates as UTC and Your Browser is Showing the local time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save in GMT timezone, you need to use `new Date()` but if you want to use your own timezone, you need to use

`new Date()
 new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), a, b, 0, 0)`

In place of `a` and `b`, you have to enter the timezone difference from GMT in hours and minutes